# Spring boot application connection to OpenTelemetry fails

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry

I have a Spring Boot REST application which simply prints `Hello world`. This works fine, now I am trying to add observability to my application, so I installed a Kind Kuberntes cluster and deployed open telemetry collector. The OpenTelemetry collector is running in the kind cluster and my spring boot app is running in my host machine. When my Spring Boot application starts it prints the following
error message:

```
[OkHttp http://otel-collector-collector.opentelemetry-operator-system.svc.cluster.local:5555/...] 
ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter -
Failed to export metrics. The request could not be executed.
Full error message: otel-collector-collector.opentelemetry-operator-
system.svc.cluster.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I have a Shell file which runs my application:

```bash
    mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

    AGENT_FILE=opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar
    if [ ! -f "${AGENT_FILE}" ]; then
      curl -L https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-java- 
    instrumentation/releases/download/v1.19.2/aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar --output 
    ${AGENT_FILE}
    fi

    export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp
    export OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp
    export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://otel-collector-collector.opentelemetry- 
    operator-system.svc.cluster.local:5555

    export OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=hello-app,service.version=1.0
    export OTEL_TRACES_SAMPLER=always_on
    export OTEL_IMR_EXPORT_INTERVAL=1000
    export OTEL_METRIC_EXPORT_INTERVAL=1000

    java -javaagent:./${AGENT_FILE} -jar target/hello-app-1.0.jar
```

I installed the OTel collector via operator:

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.10.0/cert-manager.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-operator.yaml
```

My OpenTelemetry collector config file is:

```yaml
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
  namespace: opentelemetry-operator-system
  labels:
    app: opentelemetry
    component: otel-collector
spec:
  mode: deployment
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
            endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5555
    processors:
      batch:
        timeout: 1s
        send_batch_size: 1024
    exporters:
      prometheus:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:6666
      otlp:
        endpoint: http://tempo.monitoring:3100
        tls:
          insecure: true
    service:
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [prometheus]
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp]
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Spring Boot is running on your host machine and your OpenTelemetry collector is running in a Kubernetes cluster, so what the error message is telling us is that the app can't resolve the FQDN `otel-collector-collector.opentelemetry-operator-system.svc.cluster.local`.

One way to go about it is to forward traffic from your service to your host machine:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/otel-collector-collector 5555:5555
```

… and then use this as the value for `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT`:

```
export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:5555
```